# Plot dashed regression line with geom_smooth in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a simple plot in ggplot2 and want to add a dashed regression line.  So far I have:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
  theme_bw()
```

Which returns what I want, but with a solid line:

[image: scatterplot with regression line]

I want to make the line dashed.  I think I should use `scale_linetype_manual()` but my attempts have been hacky.

A simple question, but I couldn't find a duplicate.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As per the help page (see [`?geom_smooth`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_smooth.html)), linetype is one of the aesthetics geom_smooth understands.

So, you can adjust to use `geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, linetype="dashed")`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, linetype = "dashed") +
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: Also works with `linetype = 2`. To see diferent types of lines, try  `linetype = 3`, `linetype = 4`, etc.