# R issue with linetype geom_smooth ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting regression lines from two different variables on the same plot. I'd like to make one regression line dashed, and the other solid.

I've tried using the solution suggested in a similar question: [Plot dashed regression line with geom_smooth in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34230679/plot-dashed-regression-line-with-geom-smooth-in-ggplot2), but when I use linetype="dashed" in my code, I still get solid lines. I think I must have overridden the linetype command somewhere in my code. So really, 2 questions: (1) how do I fix my code to produce dashed regression lines, and (2) is it possible to make 1 regression solid and 1 dashed on the same plot?

Any suggestions appreciated!

Current ggplot code:

```
ggplot(CanksVolumes, aes(TotalCankers, BA_05thru14_mm2, 
                         color=Site, alpha=Treatment)) + 
  scale_alpha_discrete(range = c(0.4, 1)) + 
  scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Set1') +
  geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=F, aes(fill=Site, linetype="dashed")) + 
  xlab("Total Number of Cankers per Tree") + 
  ylab("Tree Basal Area (mm^2) 2005-2014") +
  ggtitle("Total Number of Cankers Associated with Recent Growth (Basal Area Last 10 Years)") +
  facet_wrap(~Site)
```

And it's large, but a reproducible set of data:

```
CanksVolumes <- structure(list(Unique_ID_Tree = c("M3T_1", "M3T_2", "M3T_3", 
"M3T_4", "M3T_5", "M3T_6", "M3U_1", "M3U_2", "M3U_3", "M3U_4", 
"M3U_5", "M3U_6", "N1T_1", "N1T_2", "N1T_3", "N1T_4", "N1T_5", 
"N1T_6", "N1U_1", "N1U_2", "N1U_3", "N1U_4", "N1U_5", "N1U_6", 
"N2T_1", "N2T_2", "N2T_3", "N2T_4", "N2T_5", "N2T_6", "N2U_1", 
"N2U_2", "N2U_3", "N2U_4", "N2U_5", "N2U_6"), Disc_ID = c("M3T1045", 
"M3T2045", "M3T3045", "M3T4045", "M3T5045", "M3T6045", "M3U1045", 
"M3U2045", "M3U3045", "M3U4045", "M3U5045", "M3U6045", "N1T1045", 
"N1T2045", "N1T3045", "N1T4045", "N1T5045", "N1T6045", "N1U1045", 
"N1U2045", "N1U3045", "N1U4045", "N1U5045", "N1U6045", "N2T1045", 
"N2T2045", "N2T3045", "N2T4045", "N2T5045", "N2T6045", "N2U1045", 
"N2U2045", "N2U3045", "N2U4045", "N2U5045", "N2U6045"), TotalBA_mm2 = c(48422.0665741449, 
67345.5883698897, 93132.2607802485, 131867.048278746, 70774.4553777143, 
107360.658676709, 21773.5273135633, 24311.3559989519, 35102.0690873188, 
51817.4544898566, 24865.5461220263, 39005.9400223312, 24441.4199925537, 
43910.513721618, 20070.0181216216, 37068.1963964739, 49682.9417571679, 
86858.8816403778, 22417.9549103913, 35151.8985952557, 61251.0544197884, 
19683.6928319038, 30376.0140061034, 37578.4060759377, 68388.2050444103, 
65538.2384603496, 49352.4211809415, 39297.7321533062, 58503.2107932949, 
66813.9962945424, 51944.222010287, 68390.0591244299, 19013.6024003523, 
27550.4271046627, 39560.2876397285, 19580.3808789065), BA_85thru14_mm2 = c(14611.6335711751, 
45711.4998451498, 44404.7114510255, 83650.6979165133, 39953.2185049916, 
74813.8132733016, 6097.83748871461, 11675.9659731525, 11733.732636389, 
31782.0733791433, 8772.57695473424, 21371.2188664859, 11481.2053713276, 
25176.936475585, 7234.60603316087, 16459.7694084024, 32266.4395069078, 
60914.7750214847, 8231.02514160435, 16712.6392484347, 39236.2448736159, 
8996.60527146338, 12366.013456859, 23577.0687802852, 42737.3221959725, 
45669.5980237521, 28106.5850019948, 27127.3841712043, 37867.2943668496, 
44642.1681882516, 27352.3825332051, 43690.2558752766, 12840.7406254419, 
16954.3949913134, 26754.5778521084, 12128.8850034988), BA_90thru14_mm2 = c(9894.92804248437, 
36167.3432956235, 35155.176482765, 68790.9162216748, 33046.7820717523, 
61587.8471229157, 3486.06635597643, 8982.57698269882, 8583.83641098213, 
25750.4409909132, 6665.70684447704, 17971.4243926971, 7512.21138830519, 
19330.3468603148, 4458.61783312802, 11432.6404706726, 24656.1459780374, 
52524.978876548, 4933.55167452531, 10792.431696628, 31519.0778152806, 
5710.4451978927, 7394.0671124523, 19331.1910313936, 29202.1275852957, 
34989.6048109836, 21700.6971659423, 20344.6934766608, 25223.2209601062, 
32210.916157596, 20425.1667390753, 31990.4055072938, 10303.0519074308, 
13579.6935867213, 18470.724354459, 8081.36636860446), BA_95thru14_mm2 = c(4740.04634002735, 
28490.028172621, 27997.2429880936, 55112.0390582871, 27269.3294451689, 
51404.7947400297, 2273.91726244429, 6946.27671954662, 6407.33971367258, 
21356.7385496624, 4166.94646811615, 14773.5595314962, 3825.3588872101, 
14318.9577635937, 2535.89333865027, 7251.80786143471, 18995.9844461404, 
47198.4101565899, 2771.04844456734, 6794.24947471245, 25274.2196871474, 
2796.4306942262, 3428.30101220893, 15553.6019328705, 18429.9112362874, 
25781.6974753387, 15706.6985412864, 14790.3176255157, 14877.48038484, 
19672.7805789366, 12867.5381751576, 21446.4414468684, 7524.84918302853, 
9595.09411604172, 11102.2617687705, 4291.07679115986), BA_00thru14_mm2 = c(2668.97176894301, 
20957.1604073531, 22583.0193029237, 44065.3476653289, 22046.9060484913, 
42231.0690665709, 1676.88363814062, 5235.62447896369, 4398.9640151846, 
16670.8727260078, 2452.89855543217, 11330.6319456177, 583.376762896961, 
9263.89816022673, 913.416304739346, 3838.62931387087, 14006.0342876873, 
42521.6950917601, 819.828294146425, 2275.50594071647, 19359.5637568162, 
701.849592792751, 1359.72696666447, 11193.9304013406, 11317.4437752774, 
18190.5251810393, 10743.8303157992, 10742.7464663337, 7512.77441511578, 
11790.8703276434, 7618.23120253274, 14767.3494636164, 4860.00919904441, 
6318.53964422177, 6823.86677348072, 1638.34567393514), BA_05thru14_mm2 = c(1208.47399247252, 
15818.2262837189, 18911.4211191174, 34809.4601705281, 17218.2163290883, 
34546.9538971548, 1082.06713002035, 3497.33449484262, 2737.87164592433, 
12372.7144771307, 1568.68567918651, 7711.78904441141, 309.367959571136, 
6352.72038906271, 639.154383293422, 2846.52320059213, 11798.1159335768, 
33797.0001936679, 500.867418575699, 1658.15875632353, 13619.8306278706, 
351.531651566084, 457.927944832468, 6665.61686298025, 7822.17194021538, 
12104.9842818115, 7253.89335745231, 7342.93037838743, 3517.49728361725, 
7245.34692795678, 5273.63431945295, 9505.533501567, 3488.01046775825, 
4839.60067489241, 4142.03476620495, 463.990530645106), TotalCankers = c(61, 
65, 44, 31, 24, 23, 29, 37, 36, 9, 39, 24, 91, 89, 53, 61, 47, 
6, 51, 47, 39, 60, 90, 34, 34, 30, 47, 17, 62, 49, 61, 84, 59, 
84, 0, 65), WidthCankers_cm = c(131.5, 139.2, 95.6, 50, 51.2, 
76.4, 59.8, 38.8, 39.7, 13.6, 156.9, 24.3, 594.9, 136.6, 188.6, 
141.7, 275.8, 11.9, 118.8, 353, 53.7, 256.5, 347.3, 80.8, 49, 
28.2, 20.3, 5.5, 77.4, 56, 147.5, 155, 48.6, 117.4, 0, 79.1), 
    Treatment = c("T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "U", "U", "U", 
    "U", "U", "U", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "U", "U", "U", 
    "U", "U", "U", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "U", "U", "U", 
    "U", "U", "U"), Site = c("M3", "M3", "M3", "M3", "M3", "M3", 
    "M3", "M3", "M3", "M3", "M3", "M3", "N1", "N1", "N1", "N1", 
    "N1", "N1", "N1", "N1", "N1", "N1", "N1", "N1", "N2", "N2", 
    "N2", "N2", "N2", "N2", "N2", "N2", "N2", "N2", "N2", "N2"
    )), .Names = c("Unique_ID_Tree", "Disc_ID", "TotalBA_mm2", 
"BA_85thru14_mm2", "BA_90thru14_mm2", "BA_95thru14_mm2", "BA_00thru14_mm2", 
"BA_05thru14_mm2", "TotalCankers", "WidthCankers_cm", "Treatment", 
"Site"), row.names = c(NA, -36L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Take the `linetype` out of `aes`. So, your `geom_smooth` command should look like `geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=F, aes(fill=Site), linetype="dashed")`.

Comment: Great, that solved the first half of my problem and worked perfectly! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `aes(linetype=Treatment)` on `geom_smooth` and add a `scale_linetype_manual` without the need to change your data. I also used group for Treatment on the global `aes` assuming this was the original intention:

```
ggplot(CanksVolumes, aes(TotalCankers, BA_05thru14_mm2, 
                         color=Site,group=Treatment)) + 
  scale_alpha_discrete(range = c(0.4, 1)) + 
  scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Set1') +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid","dashed"))+
  geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=F, aes(linetype=Treatment)) + 
  xlab("Total Number of Cankers per Tree") + 
  ylab("Tree Basal Area (mm^2) 2005-2014") +
  ggtitle("Total Number of Cankers Associated with Recent Growth (Basal Area Last 10 Years)") +
  facet_wrap(~Site)
```

.

Answer (score 1):

```
CanksVolumes %<>% mutate(Line = ifelse(Treatment == "T", "dashed", "solid"))

ggplot(CanksVolumes, aes(TotalCankers, BA_05thru14_mm2, 
                         color=Site, alpha=Treatment)) + 
  scale_alpha_discrete(range = c(0.4, 1)) + 
  scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Set1') +
  geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=F, aes(fill=Site, linetype=Line)) + 
  xlab("Total Number of Cankers per Tree") + 
  ylab("Tree Basal Area (mm^2) 2005-2014") +
  ggtitle("Total Number of Cankers Associated with Recent Growth (Basal Area Last 10 Years)") +
  facet_wrap(~Site)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Is %<>% part of a package that I need to have? I tried the code, and received the following error: could not find function "%<>%"

Comment: Ah, yes. `library(magrittr)`

Comment: You could also write it as `CanksVolumes <- CanksVolumes %>% mutate(Line = ifelse(Treatment == "T", "dashed", "solid"))`

Comment: This produces the exact graph I'm looking for. Only issue is the legend. The solid line says "dashed" and the dashed line says "solid" next to it. Is there something I can add to specify the legend labels?

Comment: Sure. Add `scale_linetype(labels = c("Pigs In", "Spaaaaaace"))`